# Send grid c# V3 api : Not able to send mail from MVC c# web application : Response: Bad request : using "SendEmailAsync" using "RestClient"

Tags: c#, sendgrid, rest-client, sendgrid-api-v3, sendgrid-api-v2

#### Issue Summary

Response: Bad request

Not able to send mail from MVC c# web application :
getting following error
Response: Bad request : using "SendEmailAsync"  Response: Id = 8, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"  using "RestClient"

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Use the above code in any MVC application with out static class
2. Run the code
3. same error will be thrown.

#### Code Snippet

```cs
//RestClient -- var client = new RestClient("https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/mail/send");
                client.Timeout = -1;
                var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
                request.AddHeader("Authorization", "Bearer Sendgridtoken");
                request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
                request.AddParameter("application/json", "{\"personalizations\":[{\"to\":[{\"email\":\"jhon@abc.com\"}]}],\"from\":{\"email\":\"asd@xyz.com\"},\"subject\":\"testing login\",\"content\":[{\"type\":\"text/plain\",\"value\":\"tesing login login\"}]}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
                IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
                Console.WriteLine(response.Content);
```

#### Exception/Log

using "SendEmailAsync"  Response: Id = 8, Status = WaitingForActivation, Method = "{null}", Result = "{Not yet computed}"  using "RestClient"   Response: Bad request
``

#### Technical details:

- sendgrid-csharp version: SendGrid 9.22.0
- csharp version: 4.5

#### Note :

We are not using any static method for this implementation
We are not using this as a back job, we are implementing this as a method.

Comment: The sendgrid client uses `async` requests, which you have to `await`. Your log shows, you are not doing that (despite not showing any code how you use the sendgird client)

Comment: And with the RestClient response: Typically responses from sendgrid, especially with errors, contain more than just a status code but also a body which contains one or more error messages

Comment: Check if there is a `response.ErrorMessage` or `response.ErrorException` property which should explain whats wrong.

Comment: You could also try to do the same request with Postman and look at the response body